# Intel I225V 2.5G ethernet card drivers not working ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, drivers, ethernet

So I have this ethernet card from intel but im unable to find any drivers I can install on ubuntu to make it work. I know the latest kernel 5.8 has support for it but I can't update my kernel for external reasons so I want to make it work with ubuntu 20.04 and kernel 5.4. Anyone has run into this issue?

Thanks

Comment: You can backport commits from 5.8 to 5.4. But don't ask me for an instruction.